# php mysql connecting to database, reading but not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi I am trying to create a little email subscriber script for adding email addresses to my database.  I was able to get it working fine using deprecated functions like mysql_connect but am making it better using mysqli instead.  However for some reason I am no longer able to insert the email addresses into the database yet I can connect to the database fine and check the email address doesn't already exist.  I would like to know why my INSERT doesn't seem to be working.  I don't have much experience with PHP thanks.

```
    if (!$link) {
    echo "save_failed cannot connect";   //if cant connect show error
    return; 
    }
    mysqli_select_db($link,$mydb);

// Clean variables before performing insert
$clean_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);
$clean_subscriber = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['firstname']);
$clean_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['date']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM EmailList WHERE email = '{$email}'";//check if already in list
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);


if($row_cnt == 0) {   
// Perform insert if not in list
$sql = "INSERT INTO EmailList (Email,Name,Date) VALUES   
 ('$clean_email','$clean_subscriber','$clean_date')";
     echo "Thank you for Subscribing to my blog!";
} else {
    echo "You have subscribed already.  Thank you for subscribing";
}
```

Comment: You are not querying the `$sql` var.. do a `mysqli_query` the same way you did with the select.

Comment: `date` is also a reserved keyword, surround it in ticks (`)

Comment: BTW there should be no reason at all to query the DB beforehand to see if an email already exists.  Just make a unique index on the email field and go straight to the insert, handling errors in cases where there is a duplicate insert attempt.  This will save you one query against the DB every time this script is run. You should also ALWAYS check for errors in your DB interactions - when connecting, when querying, etc.  Code which handles this error cases is going to be much, much simpler to debug.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the line that runs the query:

```
mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I thought this would have fixed it but for some reason it still isn't inserting into the database.

Comment: Try `mysqli_query($link,$sql) or reportMySQLiError($mysqli);` and see what error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute the query with

> mysqli_query()

like so:

```
    if (!$link) {
    echo "save_failed cannot connect";   //if cant connect show error
    return; 
    }
    mysqli_select_db($link,$mydb);

// Clean variables before performing insert
$clean_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);
$clean_subscriber = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['firstname']);
$clean_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['date']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM EmailList WHERE email = '{$email}'";//check if already in list
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);


if($row_cnt == 0) {   
// Perform insert if not in list
$sql = "INSERT INTO EmailList (Email,Name,Date) VALUES   
 ('$clean_email','$clean_subscriber','$clean_date')";
 mysqli_query($link,$sql)
     echo "Thank you for Subscribing to my blog!";
} else {
    echo "You have subscribed already.  Thank you for subscribing";
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone think I understand where I am going wrong.  Will test it now.

Comment: I still can't get it to work with the above suggestions. I'm pickled

Comment: Are you getting any error? Try to run this function to see mysqli_error($link)

Comment: Are you [`checking for errors`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436378/php-mysql-connecting-to-database-reading-but-not-inserting#comment37809909_24436378)? @user2002077

Comment: Yes I put that in at the top and getting no errors.  I have to go now but I will be back later to try again.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2002077 By the way, you're using lowercase `e` and uppercase `E` for `email` column. `(Email,Name,Date)` and `WHERE email` so that stands to be the error. In certain DBs, lettercase matters.

Comment: Hi again.  I just tested it again there and it is/was likely actually working after adding the mysqli_select_db($link,$mydb); earlier.  I think it just took a while to update the change or something.  the lowercase letters are for retrieving the Ajax post variables and the upper case ones are the actual DB column names. Thanks all for your help